# How do you make QtCreator show cpp and header files together in left hand src tree?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

The left pane in QtCreator shows the src file tree.  All headers are in a seperate tree  `<headers>`.

Both cpp and h files are broken down by dir structure.

My cpp and h files are allways together on the storage device.  That is, each cpp file is in the same location as its matching h file.

I would like to see the h and cpp files not seperated into seperate trees in the left hand pane.  How can this be done.

On hard drive, the project layout is as follows:

```
dirA
    a.h
    a.cpp
dirB
    b.h
    b.cpp
```

I use CMake and the project imports and builds fine.

The problem is that QtCreator displays the project as so:

```
    dirA
        a.cpp
    dirB
        b.cpp

    <headers>
        dirA
            a.h
        dirB
            b.h
```

I want to see this in QtCreator left hand src tree pane.

```
dirA
    a.h
    a.cpp
dirB
    b.h
    b.cpp
```

Comment: I use Qt Creator 4.10.2 and haven't such problem. But I tried to install Qt Creator 4.11 and it split headers and sources files. Sure I use CMake based projects.

Answer (score 3):

Since Qt Creator 5 if you go to the *"Filter Tree"* drop down button, you can select *"Hide Source and Header Groups"*.

See it in action here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use CMake, you can add the headers and the source files as input for library/application targets:

```
file(glob headers include/*.h)
file(glob sources src/*.cpp)
add_executable(my_application ${sources} ${headers})
```

Or wherever and however your files are organised.

Comment: Hi, thank you but I don't quite follow you.  I use CMake and I do that, and QtCreator imports my project fine.  The problem is how it displays my files inside Qt.  It seperates the h and cpp files into seperate trees.